# Feature suggestion: enhance SE Markdown for em-dash

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I would love if the Stack Exchange implementation of Markdown converted the character sequence

`--` (two minus signs or dashes, when not part of a larger sequence of dashes)

to

— (&mdash;).

The way text looks--with two dashes--is just so much less polished than when you use a proper em-dash.

Contrast with:

The way text looks—with two dashes—is just so much less polished than when you use a proper em-dash.

Comment: Hmmm. Two-dashes in en-dash (–). Three is em-dash (—). Otherwise, TeX.SE will organize a rebellion.                     - – — – -

Comment: I could not care one iota less about TeX, even if I tried.  And there is no need for an n-dash :-)    but anything that is uniform and documented in Markdown would be an improvement.

Comment: But... without an en-dash, how would you write a range of dates (1982–83) or page numbers (p. 23–25)?

Comment: A plain dash suffices, 2-3, doncha know.